Flutter display snackbar above scrollable bottom sheet and keep the shrinkwrap of the ListView.builder
The problem is that many people suggest wrapping your bottom sheet with a Scaffold widget, but that's an issue if you have isScrollControlled: true and ListView.builder with shrinkwrap inside the bottom sheet, with this approach your listview will not shrinkwrap

So a solution i came up with:
/// Create your global key for scaffold messanger, it **must not**
/// be used in your MaterialApp widget to prevent building errors
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> snackbarKey =
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

/// Then create an overlay entry, place it somewhere 
/// in you app (Or you can just copy this directly into the stack below)
final OverlayEntry scaffoldOverylayForSnackbar = OverlayEntry(
  builder: (_) {
    return  Positioned(
      child: IgnorePointer(
        child: ScaffoldMessenger(
          key: snackbarKey,
          child: const Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            primary: false,
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            body: SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);

/// Now find your MaterialApp app, add builder inside it and create a 
/// stack that display our overlay entry above any screen we currently render
    MaterialApp(
      builder: (_, child) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            child!,
            Overlay(initialEntries: [scaffoldOverylayForSnackbar]),
          ],
        );
      },
    );

That's it, now you can call a snackbar above literally any widget in your app without loosing that shrinkwrap feature
snackbarKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      content: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('213');
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 200,
          height: 100,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

